# the rush hour or rush hour

Tags: grammar

In the beginning, I thought that the rush hour happens only once per day, so I thought it should be "**I go to work during the rush hour**". However, I figure out that not every city in the world is like my hometown, and rush hour can actually happen multiple times a day in a few cities. Therefore, it should be "**I go home every day during rush hour**".

Google suggests that both are used, what I miss here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fact that there are multiple rush hours in a particular area does not mean you cannot use the definite article with it. You can always distinguish between them by adding modifiers, e.g. *the bridge is particularly backed up during the morning rush hour* or *the accident occurred at the onramp during the lunch rush hour*.

Both *rush hour* and *the rush hour* appear to be in use. In the Google Books corpora, the definite article is somewhat more common in British usage than in American, but it has been distinctly less popular for some time in both:

[image: Phrases using "rush hour" versus "the rush hour" are roughly 8 times more prevalent in Google Books]
(there may be a few false hits for *in Rush Hour* referring to the [film](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0120812/) or its sequels, but the result is the same if you exclude the *in* phrases).

There are a few times of the day, not necessarily corresponding to a civil hour, known as an *hour*. *[Happy hour](https://www.merriam-webster.com/words-at-play/word-history-of-happy-hour)*, like *rush hour*, is mostly used without an article now, though it is mixed with *lunch hour* and *dinner hour*, whereas *the devil's hour* or *the witching hour*, rare outside literary usage, always use an article.

Saying *I want to leave before the rush hour* to my ear places a somewhat greater emphasis on a time of day, whereas *I want to leave before rush hour* is more about the conditions you want to avoid, but that is simply my personal way of drawing a distinction, and not necessarily reflective of how others use it.

Answer (score 1):

Either form amy be used. In many US cites, there are two distinct rush hours, morning and evening. In such a place, one might say:

> I go to work during the morning rush hour.

In those places with several definate rushes, one might specify the time, as in:

> I go to work during the 10:30 rush hour.

Omitting the artice, as in:

> I go home every day during rush hour.

Suggests that the listener/reader can be expected to know which rush hour is meant, from context or logic. After all, if the speker is goign home when most people go to work, s/he should make a point of that, one way or another. If no such point is made, the listener may reasonably assume that the speaker's pattern is the usual one.

By the weay, the phrase "... what I miss here?" is not correct. It should be "what **did** I miss here?" or "what am I missing here?"